# Ocaml syntax error in nested functions

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I've been staring at this code for a while now and can't figureout why I'm getting a syntax error:

```
let rec e_closure (m:nfa_t) (l:int list) = match m with
    | (_, _, (ts:transition list)) -> 
        List.sort_uniq (List.fold_left 
                            (fun (lst:int list) (state:int) -> 
                                List.fold_left 
                                    (fun (lst2:int list) (t:transition) -> 
                                        match t with 
                                        | ((start:int), (letter:char option), (end:int)) -> (if ((start = a) && (isEpilson letter)) then end::lst2 else lst2) 
                                        | _ -> raise (NFAError "e_closure match failure (nested)")) lst ts) l l)
    | _ -> raise (NFAError "e_closure match failure")
;;
```

Without getting into too much detail about this convoluted code, it's function is to return a list of the epsilon-closures of a state given a NFA (Non-deterministic Finite Automata). It's excepted types are annotated in the code.

The error message I get is on *line 8*, stating `Error: Syntax error: operator expected.`

***I suspect that knowing the functionality of the code is irelevant, but here it is nevertheless:***

`isEpsilon` is a function that returns true if the `transition` matches `None`.

`NFAError` is an user defined error.

The user defined types are:

```
type char option = None | Some of char
type transition = int * char option * int
type nfa_t = int * int list * transition list
```

An example of each type in the order listed above:

```
None
(1, None, 2)
(1, [2;3], [(1, None, 2); (1, Some 'a', 3)])
```

An example of using the function `e_closure`:

```
e_closure (1, [2,3], [(1, None, 2); (1, Some 'a', 3)]) [1] = [1;2]
```

*That is, the function looks at the list* `[(1, None, 2); (1, Some 'a', 3)]`*, returns an* `int list` *containing every element in its second parameter and every epsilon transition of all the elements of that parameter. In this case, since the second parameter is* `[1]`, it will return `[1;2]`, the transition `(1, Some 'a', 3)` *is not an epsilon transition, so it's not included.*

The code uses the function `fold_left` and `sort_uniq` found in Ocaml's native module [List](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html).

Comment: Note the coloring of `end` in the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `end` as an identifier but it is a keyword in OCaml.

Comment: Wow, I'm not even shocked